# /db/data/batch endpoint running out of memory

Tags: neo4j

I am currently sending json batches (mass creating nodes and relationships) to my neo4j instance at http://host:7474/db/data/batch. These batches have grown in size and now I am getting the error shown below.

Seemingly this error is caused when trying to create the response to the request, which is just too big and blowing up an Array?

Is there a way around this and still allow the use of the json batch endpoint? The json is being created by a downstream process and so moving to some other mechanism (e.g. csv loading) is not possible due to the necessary changes in other processes.

Is there any way around this? It is not possible to do multiple smaller batches because of the many relationships between the nodes being created. Later nodes and relationships being created refer to node IDs from earlier on the batch. If I break the batch up then I'll refer to node IDs which don't exist in the current transaction.

```
2015-05-27 13:15:16.425+0000 INFO  [API] Remote interface ready and available at [http://localhost:7474/]
09:18:38.822 [qtp20290798-38] WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620) [jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540) [jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
.
.
.
```

Comment: what are the requests you're sending to the batch endpoint? Do you have a more complete stacktrace - so we could understand the root cause.

Comment: Limit it to 10k nodes that you create and use `-H X-Stream:true` as header

Comment: It sounds like a serious issue. I.e. an array in java that has more than 2bn entries is created.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Adding the `X-Stream:true`  header did the trick! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. This worked for ~40k nodes with ~5m edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit it to 10k nodes that you create and use -H X-Stream:true as header then it doesn't build up gigantic json response strings in memory.